# 'Refresh' Jquery event on keyup

Tags: jquery, events, dynamic

I have this script which generates 50 'a' tags on keyup:

```
$("#searchbox").live("keyup",function(){
    var count = 50;
    var aElements = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        aElements += "<a href=\"#\">" + i + "</a>";
    }

    $("#page").append(aElements);
});
```

The problem is that the amount ads up on every keyup. So instead of firing event for specific amount of 50 the code ads up the count. So for each 'keyup' I get 50 + 50 + 50 'a' tags and so on. So when I type 'stackoverflow' I get 650 'a' tags:) instead of 50. So how do I do this? Please keep in mind that the number is in fact a var which changes every time so adding event .one() wont work.

Comment: Thank you guys, I will look in to it But it is going to take a while to see what works for my script, please be patient regarding acceptance..

Comment: s (keyup) -> 50 **a** tags + a (keyup) -> 50 **a** tags + … will naturally be 13x50=650 **a** tags. What are you exactly willing to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `.append()` which, as the name says, adds the new elements but doesn't remove the previous ones. Add a container at the end of `#page` and use `.html()` so that the old content gets removed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your requirements, but I believe this is what you're looking for:

**Option 1**

```
$("#page").html(""); //Clear HTML from #page
```

**Option 2**

```
$("#page a").remove(); //Clear only the anchor tags from #page
```

**Option 3**

Simply replace `.append()` with `.html()`. Unless you have a specific reason to use `.append()`, this is the best option.

```
$("#page").html(aElements);
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/k6ERU/).

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, each time the number will change (can be bigger or smaller) and you need to update it to have the number of `a` tags equal to that number.

I think the best bet would be to see how many exist already and act accordingly (unless the overall number stays small, in which case, just wipe them and re-create each time).  To do this, I would add a shared class to each of these `a` tags:

```
aElements += "<a href=\"#\" class=\"number\">" + i + "</a>";
```

And then do the following to see how many already exist:

```
var existing = $(".number").length
```

Then, if the number is less than how many I want to have:

```
for (var i = existing; i < count; i++) {
    // add more
```

And if it is more, do the following to remove the excess:

```
$(".number").gt(count).remove();
```